# Mongoose find is returning a blank array, RoboMongo finds data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've got an Express application which until this morning was returning an array of objects from the database. Now it's returning an empty array. RoboMongo shows me that the data is still there and doing fine. Any ideas?

My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const plotStatusSchema = new Schema(
    {
        recordDate: Date,
        blockName: String,
        growerName: String,
        company: String,
        variety: String,
        planted: Number,
        region: String,
        yieldInKG: Number,
        changeInPcnt: Number,
        currentRipeness: String,
        nextStage: String,
        timeToNextInDays: Number,
        status: Number
    },
    { bufferCommands: false },
    { collection: 'plotStatuses' }
);

const ModelClass = mongoose.model(
    'plotStatus',
    plotStatusSchema,
    'plotStatuses'
);

module.exports = ModelClass;
```

My returning controller:

```
const PlotStatus = require('../models/plotStatus');
const jsonpack = require('jsonpack');

exports.plotStatuses = async (req, res) => {
    const plotStatus = await PlotStatus.find({
        company: 'req.user.companyCode'
    }).lean();
    if (!plotStatus) {
        throw new Error('Plot Statuses not found');
    } else {
        res.send(plotStatus);
    }
};
```

A sample of my data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId,
    "recordDate" : ISODate,
    "blockName" : String,
    "blockCode" : String,
    "growerName" : String,
    "company" : String,
    "variety" : String,
    "planted" : ISODate,
    "region" : String,
    "yieldInKG" : Number,
    "changeInPcnt" : Number,
    "currentRipeness" : String,
    "nextStage" :String,
    "timeToNextInDays" : Number,
    "status" : Number,
    "targetYieldInKG" : Number,
    "currentStatePercentage" : Number,
    "totalLengthOfPhase" : Number,
    "nextPhaseStart" : ISODate,
    "currentBrix" : Number,
    "currentPh" : Number,
    "currentTA" : Number,
    "plotGeoJSON" : Object,
    "historicalData" : Array
}
```

I know that the Schema no longer matches the shape of the JSON, but can I return all the JSONs that fit the find condition anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching the string "req.user.companyCode" inside the `company` attribute. Obviously, you don't have that company code in your data. Try it again without the quores:

```
const plotStatus = await PlotStatus.find({
    company: req.user.companyCode
}).lean();
```